# li floats do not hide

Tags: html, css

I copied the `css` from the [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/) site itself, but I do not get the same result. I want the floating `li` elements to disappear when they overflow at the right end of the screen, but they always appear below the container.

https://jsfiddle.net/qeub71Lp/

```css
.w3-left {
float: left!important;
}
.w3-navbar {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
.w3-navbar li {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-card-2 w3-slim topnav" id="topnav" style="position: relative;">
    <div style="overflow:auto;">
        <ul class="w3-navbar w3-left"
    style="width:55%;overflow:hidden;height:44px">
            <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">JAVASCRIPT</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">SQL</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">PHP</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">BOOTSTRAP</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">JQUERY</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">ANGULAR</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">XML</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">W3.CSS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the link where you got it from ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to reduce the height of `ul`

```
<ul class="w3-navbar w3-left" style="width:55%;overflow:hidden;height:20px">
```

Here is updated [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qeub71Lp/3/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced you should be using `floats` for this at all.

Standard `float` behaviour is that when there is no more horizontal space left, the next element will be displayed on the next line down.

Consequently `inline-block` might be a better choice than `float`.

**Working Example:**

```css
.topnav {
position: relative;
left: 50vw;
width: 50vw;
background-color: rgb(191,191,191);
overflow: hidden;
}

.w3-navbar {
height:1.4em;
line-height: 1.4em;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
overflow: hidden;
}

.w3-navbar li {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">

<ul class="w3-navbar">
<li><a>HTML</a></li>
<li><a>CSS</a></li>
<li><a>JAVASCRIPT</a></li>
<li><a>SQL</a></li>
<li><a>PHP</a></li>
<li><a>BOOTSTRAP</a></li>
<li><a>JQUERY</a></li>
<li><a>ANGULAR</a></li>
<li><a>XML</a></li>
<li><a>W3.CSS</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

HTML

```
<div class="w3-card-2 w3-slim topnav" id="topnav" style="position: relative;">
      <div style="overflow:auto;">
        <ul class="w3-navbar w3-left" style="width:55%;overflow:hidden;height:20px;">
          <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">JAVASCRIPT</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">SQL</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">PHP</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">BOOTSTRAP</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">JQUERY</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">ANGULAR</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">XML</a></li>
          <li><a href="" class="w3-hide-small">W3.CSS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
    .w3-left {
    float: left!important;
}

.w3-navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:44px
}

ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.w3-navbar li {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```